# Sorting a csv file in Python with sorted() returns values in programmer DESC order, not time DESC order

Tags: python, numerical, sorting

I'm not doing anything overly complex I believe. I'm presorting a large csv data file because it is full of data that arrives in random time order. The index is correct, but the return formatting is off.

```
    sortedList=sorted(reader,key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

So instead of sorting like [-100 -10 -1 0 10 100 5000 6000]; I get [-1 -10 -100 0 100 5000 60]

I tried both the lambda function examples and itemgetter, but I don't really know where to go from there.

Thanks for the help.

The answer to my question is in the comments. The numerical value was being sorted as a string and not a number. I didn't know that I could specify the data type of the key in sorted(). This code works as I intended:

```
    sortedList=sorted(reader,key=lambda x:float(x[1]))
```

Comment: It would help if you posted an example of the data in reader.

Comment: are the content in reader strings? then you will get string based sort which explains the result. If ints, correct list is returned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just from the output you see there, it looks like these are being sorted as strings rather than as numbers.

So you could do:

```
sortedList=sorted(reader, key=lambda t: int( t[1] ))
```

or

```
sortedList=sorted(reader, key=lambda t: float( t[1] ))
```

Or better, try to ensure that the sequence `reader` gets populated with numbers, rather than strings, when it's created, perhaps using QUOTE_NONNUMERIC as a fmtparam for the reader (see http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC).

Comment: Welcome.  Note that strictly speaking you aren't specifying the type of the data in the key as such - it's just that float(x) gives you the conversion of x from string to float.  You can actually use an arbitrary complex function of one variable as your `key` - either using a lambda or an inner function like `def f(t): return float( t[1] )` (in which case you use `key=f` when you do your sort)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "reader" yields strings, and what you want is integers. You could try something like :

```
    sorted(reader, key=lambda x: float(x[1]))
```

Comment: They are 'doubles' as they represent a time value.
I tried your code and it chokes on this:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.06949624419212341'

Comment: @mike : try float instead of int.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your numbers are getting sorted alphabetically (as strings) rather than numerically:

```
>>> sorted([10,2000,30])
[10, 30, 2000]
>>> sorted(['10','2000','30'])
['10', '2000', '30']
```

To fix this, you can pass a numeric sort:

```
def numeric_compare(x, y):
    return int(x)-int(y)

>>> sorted(['10','2000','30'],cmp=numeric_compare)
['10', '30', '2000']
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your list is being sorted as strings rather than numbers. When you read in your CSV file, it is still text and must be converted to integers first.

Answer (score 0):

I like `compose`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def compose(f, g):
    return lambda *a, **k: g(f(*a, **k))

sortedList = sorted(reader, key=compose(itemgetter(1), float))
```